how can i extract the form information from a .mdb file?
I am after the form specification data - all the parameters you would type in in the design view for a form.
I have used jackess to access the .mdb file.
I fiddled with permissions on MSysObjects table and made it public and was able to access the data.
I found that the form information was present but it was an OLE field.
Dumping that data gave me some OLE data - but it was clearly a reference - something i have no idea how to continue with in java - the language I used.
I find it hard to imagine that I am the only person that would like to extract this information yet i've not found any tools or strategies on how to extract the form information from access.
Anyone have any suggestions or recommendations?

How many database do you need to process?

well just the one - there about 100 forms in it, a bit to much to do manually

You are probably the only one, because that information is useless without Access.
Still, you can, though with the help of Access, export those data with the VBA command:
SaveAsText acForm, "TheFormName", "d:\path\TheFormName.txt"

acForm is an integer constant having the value of 2.

As it turns out, thats probably not the case.  The data is actually useful without access.  The form definitions are useful in that i can feed them into other tools and recreate code to implement something that resembles the access app in something a bit more  long term maintainable.   I can get the data manually but for 100+ screens its not real practical esp when forms have buttons /sub forms etc.    as far as that command, what would it actually save?  Where would I execute it?   Access is not the center of my expertise.

As it turns out, that is exactally what I was after.  Thank you.
